# How to send a double click message to the specified listview element

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I send a double click message to the specified listview element in Windows? I know that i need to use SendMessage function, but I'm not sure about an arguments to this function. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Use ListView_SetItemState macro. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775102(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @g_news_list_view_handle I think that it's just select an item, but not double click it

Comment: @FrozenHeart If it's your own code, it's easier to directly call the code that you want to be invoked on a dblclick. why do you want to fake the event?

Comment: Manuell, good comment.

Comment: `NM_DBLCLK` is the [notification message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774867(v=vs.85).aspx) sent on a double-click.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Yes, but i don't know which other parameters should i use to do it. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Have you been able to use my answer?

Answer (score 0):

How to fake a NM_DBLCLK notification:

```
#include <Commctrl.h>
// ensure those variables are ok
HWND hWndListViewParent;
INT iListViewID;
HWND hWndListView;

[...]

NMITEMACTIVATE nmia;
nmia.hdr.code = NM_DBLCLK;
nmia.hdr.hwndFrom = hWndListView;
nmia.hdr.idFrom = iListViewID;
// set up the rest of NMITEMACTIVATE

[...]

SendMessage( hWndListViewParent, WM_NOTIFY, (WPARAM)iListViewID, (LPARAM)&nmia );
```

I don't think you can do that cross process, however. Try it. If that indedd doesn't work, you will have to fake mouse action via SendInput, or maybe use UIAutomation.